# Civisualize - getting data from a report into dataviz

Tags: civireport, civisualize

I'm seeing in notes on Civizualize that some work has been done in getting reports data into a form where civisualize can deal with it.

Anyone give me a pointer to where that is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In principle, if you get the data out of report as json or csv, it should work fine.

Let me check with sid if he remembers what was done beside fetching as csv.